# Assistance Required with Running Python Server

Tags: python, django

I am trying to execute 'python manage.py runserver' and keep receiving this error message. I have tried using SQL_Server.pyodbc and SQLServer_ADO as SQL Engines - but this does not appear to resolve the errors I am receiving. I have also excluded a few new python files from my project which I recently added since the system worked fine prior to adding in new python files.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\shareddrives.nkfaulknerandsons.co.uk\Tutoring\PhD\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".\polls\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 184, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
The interactive Python process has exited.
The interactive Python process has exited.
```

EDIT: I have upgraded Django to 3.0.2, I have also installed django-mssql-backend. However, now I recieve the following error in command prompt:

```
    '\\shareddrives.nkfaulknerandsons.co.uk\Tutoring\PhD\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "\\shareddrives.nkfaulknerandsons.co.uk\Tutoring\PhD\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\polls\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d.%d is not supported." % VERSION[:3])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 3.0.2 is not supported.
```

EDIT2: I have downgraded to Python 2.1 and am now recieving the following:

```
'\\shareddrives.nkfaulknerandsons.co.uk\Tutoring\PhD\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000002410E25C798>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "\\shareddrives.nkfaulknerandsons.co.uk\Tutoring\PhD\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\polls\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 304, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\base.py", line 98, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d is not supported." % DjangoVersion[:2])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 2.1 is not supported.
```

Comment: Looks like the database is incompatible or not configured properly. For more specific help you will have to add more detailed information.

Comment: Please could you outline more detailed information required? I'm able to connect to and log in to the SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Can you share your `DATABASES` setting and your `Question` model?

Comment: DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': "sqlserver_ado",
       'HOST': "websiteurlhere,1434",
       'USER': "username",
       'PASSWORD': "password",
       'NAME': "Django",
       'OPTIONS': {
           'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
           'unicode_results': True,
           'host_is_server': True
       },
   }
}

Comment: from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

Comment: Are you using django-mssql? https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql/

Comment: Looks like it's been replaced by this package if it's the case https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Comment: django-mssql-backend only supports up to Django2.2. https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend/issues/18

Comment: Do you know where I can obtain Django2.2?

Comment: Please see additional 'edit2' above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the database is incompatible or not configured properly. For more specific help you will have to add more detailed information i woild think.